# Syntax error using ODBC driver for SQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to make a item shop for a game server and I am using code written by someone else. I have worked my way through a few errors but this one has me scratching my head.

On the return trip from PayPal sandbox I end up with this error.

> The Error : SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
>   Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '='. The Error in :
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\shop\include\querydbSQL.php Line : 98

I have already confirmed the PDO drivers, PHP versions, MySQL and SQLSERVER access.

```
function Update($dbname, $table, $array, $where) {
    try {
        $parts = array();
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $parts[] = "[" . $key . "] = '" . $value . "'";
        }
        $sth = $this->dbSql->prepare("UPDATE [$dbname].[dbo].[$table] SET " . implode(",", $parts) . " WHERE $where");
        $data = $sth->execute();     <-------- Line 98 
        return $data;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        if(DEV_MODE === true){
            echo "The Error : " . $ex->getMessage() . "<br />";
            echo "The Error in : " . $ex->getFile() . "<br />";
            echo "Line : " . $ex->getLine() . "<br />";
        } else {
            echo "[2004]The System has some error, Please contact with Administrator!";
        }
        die;
    }
```

Any guidance at all is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
function SelectWhere($dbname, $table, $where) {
    try {
        $sth = $this->dbSql->prepare("SELECT * FROM [$dbname].[dbo].[$table] WHERE $where ");
        $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $sth->execute();
        $data = $sth->fetchAll();
        return $data;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        if(DEV_MODE === true){
            echo "The Error : " . $ex->getMessage() . "<br />";
            echo "The Error in : " . $ex->getFile() . "<br />";
            echo "Line : " . $ex->getLine() . "<br />";
        } else {
            echo "[2003]The System has some error, Please contact with Administrator!";
        }
        die;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at your SQL query? Looks like it's an invalid format

Comment: Can you provide the variables being passed? And I'm not going to start on the possible SQL Injection issue here.

Comment: Can you print the statement before executing it and share it with us?

Comment: Array ([dbname] => Auth[table] => Account[array] => Array([point] => 50)[where] => [account_id] =[parts] => Array([0] => [point] = '50')[value] => 50[key] => point ) array(7) refcount(2){["dbname"]=>string(4) "Auth" refcount(1)["table"]=>string(7) "Account" refcount(1)["array"]=>array(1) refcount(2){["point"]=>int(50)}["where"]=>string(15) "[account_id] = " refcount(1)["parts"]=>array(1) refcount(2){[0]=>string(14) "[point] = '50'" refcount(1)}["value"]=>int

Comment: WEI_DBA above is all of the defined variables print.

Comment: @DerekPollard  I think you are correct.  The where variable seems to be the account id.  Another error I received was due to this column being an INT and it is being fetched as a string. I havnt worked out the correct way to do this though. I will place the function that fetches the variable in the original post.

Comment: Ok so var_dump for $sth gives: object(PDOStatement)#30 (1) {["queryString"]=>string(70) "UPDATE [Auth].[dbo].[Account] SET [point] = '50' WHERE [account_id] = " }     [account_id] = should be (my assumption) [account_id] = '12'

Comment: The only place I can find [account_id] in the files is:  public function updatePoint($accountId, $point){
  $query = new querydbSQL();
  return $query->Update(DB_AUTH, "Account", array("point" => $point), "[account_id] = $accountId");
 }